# Laravel model relationships many-to-many or has many through

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am struggling to work what the correct relationship for my data models would be so I come seeking advice, I have the following tables.

**custom_fields**

| id | key | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | faveColor | Favourite Colour |

**campaigns**

| id | name | client_id | last_imported |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Acme Campaign | 1 | 2023-11-14 19:06:00 |

**subscribers**

| id | name | email | active |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jane Doe | jane.doe@email.com | 1 |

**campaign_subscriber**

| id | campaign_id | subcriber_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

**campaign_custom_field**

| id | campaign_id | custom_field_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

What I am trying to achieve is that a campaign can have many custom fields assigned too it. Using that relation I need to be able to somehow lookup the custom fields for each subscriber that is is in that campaign. I feel like subscriber has a many to many relationship with custom_field too with the addition of some pivot data?

**custom_field_subscriber**

| id | subscriber_id | custom_field_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Blue |

But the question remains how to I get the custom fields each subscriber in that campaign?

`$campaign->subscribers->customFields` I assume would return all the custom fields not just the ones relevant to the campaign I want?

Do I need a has many through? Would that make difference?

Comment: Do you want all the `custom_fields` that attached with the `subscribers` of the selected `campaign`?

Comment: Laravel code (https://paiza.io/projects/nXrtGHW_7_N4egcMmWKnCQ)

Comment: Based on tables in post, you dont have any relationship between custom_fields and subscribers. Only between campaingns and custom_fields. In this state, only campaingn has custom field. Subscriber has only campaigns, which can have custom_
fields. You have to add another table for relationship between subsribers and custom_fields and/or subscribers, campaigns and custom_fields (based on if you want custom_field for subscriber fol all campaigns or for specific campaign)